# How do I get a MOTU 828 MK II working?

Tags: sound, jack, motu, firewire

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.10, which is proving to be a nice OS - it's pretty fun to learn. I was wondering how to get Ubuntu to recognize my [MOTU 828 Mk II](http://www.motu.com/products/motuaudio/copy2_of_828) firewire audio DSP (?) unit. It's connected by firewire to the valid FireWire port on my computer, and so (I believe) is being recognized by Jack.

When I start Jack, it starts the server (unlike when I had the 828 plugged in to another Firewire port that I don't remember ever using, and so must be inactive), but the client can't connect... After this, I try to stop the server, but it, for whatever reason, won't stop. I then close Jack to try to start the server again, only to find that I can't restart the server (perhaps because the server wasn't ended..?).

The server's location is /usr/bin/jackd. The settings of CJackCtl is set as is shown in [step 4 of the Firewire page on Ubuntu's community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FireWire#Step_4_-_Start_Jack). Any ideas?

Oh, and if there's another way of using my DSP with Ubuntu other than using Jack, I'm open for suggestions.

I'm also looking into FFADO as a way to send audio from my computer to the DSP.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!